# Do Archaea have membrane-bound organelles?

Tags: bacteriology, archaea, organelle

From Campbell Ch. 6 Intro to the Cell,

Which of the following statements concerning bacteria and archaea cells is correct?

A) Archaea cells contain small membrane-enclosed organelles; bacteria do not.

B) Archaea cells contain a membrane-bound nucleus; bacteria do not.

C) DNA is present in both archaea cells and bacteria cells.

D) DNA is present in the mitochondria of both bacteria and archaea cells.

(A) is correct. My logic was that Archaea and Bacteria were originally from the same family as they are prokaryotes with membrane-less organelles. Is this thinking correct? If not, where am I wrong?

Comment: Surely the answer is C.

Answer (score 5):

```
A) Archaea cells contain small membrane-enclosed organelles; bacteria do not.
```

*FALSE*. As you said, Archaea and Bacteria are prokaryotes: that don't have any nucleus nor membrane-bound organelles.

```
B) Archaea cells contain a membrane-bound nucleus; bacteria do not.
```

*FALSE*. See comment above.

```
C) DNA is present in both archaea cells and bacteria cells.
```

**TRUE**. Apart from some kind of viruses, all living organisms<sup>*</sup> have DNA as the support of their genome. It confirms that other choices are false.

```
D) DNA is present in the mitochondria of both bacteria and archaea cells.
```

*FALSE*. See comment for answer A: neither of them have mitochondria.

More info: [Archaea on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaea)

(*) Viruses aren't always considered living organisms.